# How do I log in using python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

path = r'C:\Users\test\Documents\Python Scripts\chromedriver.exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)

driver.get("http:\\www.wyzant.com")
link = driver.find_element_by_link_text("LOG IN")
link.click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "username")))

username = driver.find_element_by_id("Username")
username.send_keys("test")
```

The code isn't sending "test" into the username id. I think once I'm able to plug in the username, I should be able to figure out how to plug in the password and click login.

Comment: It looks like the element name is misspelt.  It should be `Username` not `username` in the `WebDriverWait` line. Can you please check that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things to change here. The element id is `Username` not `username` and using `find_element_by_css_selector` seems to work.

So, changes will be as below

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "Username")))

username = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".sso-login-form > div:nth-child(2) > input:nth-child(2)")
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Do you know why I need to use css_selector instead of find by id?

Comment: Glad to hear that. I am not very good with websites but I think it has something to do with different HTML frames since login is a popup on the main page.

Answer (score 0):

in javascript i use this function |

```
const button = await driver.wait(
      until.elementLocated(By.xpath('your xpath element')), 12000).then(button => {
      return driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(button4),12000)},  function(button4) {
          if (button instanceof Error) {
            bot.sendMessage(-*****chatID,"Card info"+console.log(button)+"CRASH!⛔️");
              console.log(button, 'fail');
              console.log(Date(time));
              return WebDriver.quit();
          }
        })
      button.sendKeys('your text').then(async function() {
      console.log(button.sendKeys,'input info - done');
      return true//it existed
    })
```

Comment: I'm looking to learn how to do this in python. I'm very much a beginner, and I want to log into the wyzant portal.